# VB.net functions accessible in any .vbhtml file (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I've written some functions in .vb files for my asp forms applications, but I'm porting it over to MVC4 and I need to be able to access some functions in the Views (.vbhtml files).

Can I globally declare these somewhere?

I already attempted to include the .vb file in hopes that I'd have access to the functions within the View.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you write them as [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) for `System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`